# Como verificar existência de determinado array em um outro array?

Tags: javascript, array

Em determinado momento em meu sistema, preciso consumir um método que me retorna um array, que pode conter arrays.

Eu preciso alimentar um segundo *array* com dados contidos no *array* principal.
Veja exemplo?

```
arrayRetorno[0] = item[i].tasks[0].colleagueId;
```

Pode ocorrer alguns casos que o *array* tasks não exista, então como  verificar se existe um *array* *task* contido no *array* **item**?

Comment: Tem que fazer if ne... Tenta fazer assim: !!item[i].tasks

Comment: Se é o `tasks` que pode não existir então o que pretende fazer é `if (item[i].tasks) { ...`